# JavaEE TreeSet causes org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, sortedset

I've got a Class A. A has a TreeSet of B. B has a TreeSet of C. C has a HashSet of D.

I'm getting this Exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : D.c -> C

I understand why I normally would get that exception. But in this case I really can't imagine why, because when I change the type of B.cSortedSet to a normal set it will work. Has anyone an idea?

Classes with better readability can be found here:

```
@Entity
public class A extends SortableEntity  {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = „a“, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OrderBy("sortOrder")
    public SortedSet<B> bSortedSet = new TreeSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class B extends SortableEntity  {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = „b“, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OrderBy("sortOrder")
    public SortedSet<C> cSortedSet = new TreeSet<>(); // Wont work.
    // public Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>(); // Will work.

    @ManyToOne
    public A a;
}

@Entity
public class C extends SortableEntity  {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = „c“, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Set<D> dSet = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    public B b;
}

@Entity
public class D  {
    @ManyToOne
    public C c;
}

@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class D  {
    @ManyToOne
    public Integer sortOrder;
}
```

Note: Normally the properties are all private and they have getters and setters. Comparable is implemented and equal methods are overridden.

**Edit:**

---

Anil's answer was correct. It seems to be the problem, that when the tree set is rearranging it's elements it's destroying the back references and they need to be persisted again. This is just my best thought. I have no prove for that, but with manipulating the data (so that the set has not to sort itself), I can get it work.

Comment: Maybe your JPA provider only supports particular collection types, and SortedSet is not one of them? The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus JPA) in my application definitely supports SortedSet/TreeSet declarations, but can't comment on the others

Comment: The TreeSet is supported. The other one worked well.

Comment: The other comment would be that OrderBy on a Set is redundant since the elements when retrieved will be ordered by the set itself, not the order of adding them.

Comment: Hibernate will throw an exception when the annotation is missing. At first I had the same thought. How ever, the answer solved the problem. Any idea why that is working? (See Anlis answer)

Comment: First of all, do not use public access modifier for entity instance variables. JPA 2.1 spec is pretty clear: The instance variables of a class must be private, protected, or package visibility independent of
whether field access or property access is used.

Comment: And if you had read the note in my post, you would have seen that there is a note saying, that all these properties are private in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen when you have a collection in your entity, and that collection has one or more items which are not present in the database.

For your code above, it has to do with CASCADE property for  @ManyToOne
Use cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, and test the results.

Comment: That solves my problem. But why do I need to add a cascade type for the back reference? When the most top entity is saved, the cascade should save all other entities as well. And why the hell does that only affect the tree set and not the hash set?